# Having bitmaps available throughout the application

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, static

I have an application that when it starts it reads a GIF, extracts multiple bitmaps from the GIF and then makes this bitmaps available throughout the application for drawing in other classes. For example:

```
public class Images
{
    public static Bitmap pic1, pic2, pic3;
    public static void MakeBitmaps(string pathToGif)
    {
       var bigPic = new Bitmap(pathToGif);
       pic1 = bigPic.Clone(new Rectangle(1,1,100,100));
       pic2 = bigPic.Clone(new Rectangle(101,1,100,100));
       pic3 = bigPic.Clone(new Rectangle(201,1,100,100));
    }
}
```

This way, I can access all three bitmaps in other classes by simply using:

```
g.DrawImage(Images.pic1, x, y)
g.DrawImage(Images.pic2, x, y)
```

etc.

I open up several GIFs this way and extract sub-images from them to be used in my program. In the end there are lots of these bitmaps, even though they are quite small (less than 100x100 px).

While this works fine, is there a more optimal way of doing this? Should I avoid static modifier with Bitmaps and can it cause memory problems when there are multitudes of these bitmaps?

Comment: Make class static or an instance of the class static.

Answer (score -1):

In case you need something global, it's always nice to consider using the [singletons](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton) pattern

And then you create a class which holds your bitmaps, here's a rough sketch:

```
// Add singleton pattern to this class
class MyBitmaps
{
   // populate the list somewhere
   public List<Bitmap> bitmaps {get; set;}

   // Or even use a dictionary where the key is a name or another identifier
   public Dictionary<string, Bitmap> {get;set;}
}
```